# How can you see your Facebook Groups in Facebook for Android?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, facebook

I downloaded facebook for Android latest version just now.

This version is much better than the one which was pre-installed on my Samsung Galaxy S phone.

But can I see my Facebook **groups** somewhere in this version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups are not available in the Facebook app.  You'll have to go to the website via [m.facebook.com](http://m.facebook.com) or [touch.facebook.com](http://touch.facebook.com)

Comment: "Groups" was released on Facebook only a short time ago. The app pre-dates it by quite a bit.

Comment: @Al it's slightly confusing, because there are two different group features on FB.  There is the old Group system and the New one they just rolled out.

Comment: Wasn't the old Groups called "Lists" though?

Comment: No the old groups was similar to fan pages, but with some different permissions. I believe they predate android.

Answer (score 3):

[Facebook have just released](http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=446167297130) version 1.4 of their official Facebook app for Android, this has support for both the new Places and Groups features (this is the new Groups feature where you can group your friends, not the old Groups feature which is a bit like the current Pages feature).

If you've already got the official Facebook app installed, then you should be able to update though the Market app. Otherwise just download it from there!

Comment: @GA Thrawn: this still doesn't show me a list of all my groups, ready for me to enter a comment on the group page.